# Query a form excluding some fields in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I have a container which have some list for forms. I am writing a query to get all the fields which have some value.

```
 var value = 'gettingFromATextField';

mainPanel.query('form > field[value*='+value+']');
```

it is retrieving all the fields which have that value.How to exclude some fields even it matches the value. for Example if i have textfield Test ,Even if the value matches the Test field should not be retrived. Kindly help me

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. You want all fields that match the value, except for sometimes when you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

we can use != Operator

```
     mainPanel.query('form > field[value*='+value+'][name!=excludigFieldName]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude any fields adding `:not` pseudo-selector in your query. Lets say all fields you want to exclude has class *excluded-field*, then your code should be something like this:

```
var value = 'gettingFromATextField';

mainPanel.query('form > field[value*='+value+']:not(.excluded-field)');
```